# How change the file codification in XCode 4

Tags: xcode, configuration, utf-8, character-encoding, xcode4

I am having bad times with my CVS and Xcode 4.0.2. Are there a easy way to change the codification of all files? I have to use `UTF8`, because I use portuguese accents.

If I enter a non ASCII character like `¹²³` (`option` + (1, 2, 3)), the Xcode show the screen: `Encoding Conflict` than I can convert to UTF8.

It change in my `(program name).xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` the config line of this file from

```
{isa = PBXFileReference; lastKnownFileType = sourcecode.c.h; path = myfile.pch; sourceTree = "<group>"; };
```

to

```
{isa = PBXFileReference; fileEncoding = 4; lastKnownFileType = sourcecode.c.h; path = myfile.pch; sourceTree = "<group>"; };
```

(Look the change of `fileEncoding = 4;`)

My question is: How I change all files to this encoding (or only one encoding)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't found this documented anywhere, but my tests indicate `fileEncoding = 4` corresponds to Unicode (UTF-8). Sounds like you are good there. You can also set your default encoding to UTF-8 in Xcode preferences.

So, CVS... can we talk? This is ancient technology. You might as well be asking about writing to 5.25" floppy drives. At the very least, you should be upgrading to subversion pronto. Better -- no, make that **way better** -- upgrade to git or mercurial. You don't need to invest a moment longer in technology that's been obsolete for years. I actually like using git, and consider it possibly my most valuable tool.

Comment: My company use it... It's a bank and I believe exist codes from 1980s running today :) To fix this problem, I change this config and remake the project, and the problem no more show.

Comment: This must be new development, right? Other than hidebound tradition, there's probably no technical reason you couldn't set up, e.g. a subversion server -- for new projects only -- on the same hardware CVS is on. The software is free. Somebody must advocate for change, right? Might as well be you.

Comment: Lol. I do not understand my company. The things are so difficult. Yes, for this project I create a local git server and work with it. But we have to commit in our CVS... One thing you have to imagine is a 20 year of program history. Convert or change it will not be easy.. This is a legacy system problem...

Comment: Been there. You could always use git as your (sub rosa) _real_ repository, and checkin to CVS what you've got every so often, say once every 2 weeks. Who's to know?

Answer (score 0):

You want to change the lines of source code files in project.pbxproj? In Terminal.app, execute the following shell commands

```
$ mv your_program_name.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj project.pbxproj.orig
$ sed -e 's/\(PBXFileReference;\) \(lastKnownFileType = sourcecode\)/\1 fileEncoding = 4; \2/' project.pbxproj.orig > your_program_name.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
```

Comment: OK, this is a copy and paste text. Is this the best way you know? I have already change in the `config->Text Editing->Default text encoding` and set to UTF-8 (and check on "Convert existing files on save"). Maybe, i do that before create this file and because this do not change. But thanks, I will try your way. :P