# rake aborted! /... invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII error each time I attempt a "rake db:migrate"

Tags: character-encoding, rake, migrate

I get the following error message:

> "rake aborted! /... invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII"

each time I attempt a "rake db:migrate"

I'm using Rails 3.2.13 and rvm 1.20.12

I tried to insert "`#encoding: utf-8"` at the top of every file in which I typed anything and at the top of the rakefile and gemfile, but it still produces the same error and I'm stuck.
Maybe it's to do with yet another file, but I have no idea which...

EDIT the migration file in question

```
class CreateClients < ActiveRecord::Migration 
    def change create_table 
      :clients do |t| 
        t.string :code 
        t.string :nom 
        t.string :adresse 
        t.string :ville 
        t.string :code_postal 
        t.string :pays t.string :mel 
        t.string :password 
        t.boolean :actif 
        t.float :calculs 
        t.date :date_inscription 
        t.timestamps 
      end 
    end 
end
```

Comment: Can you post your migration files? Have you tried running one migration at a time? Have you tried saving the files in utf 8?

Comment: I'm not sure how to save them in UTF8. I'm using XCode on MacOSX

Comment: When you say "running one migration at a time", you mean directly in Sqlite3 ? I'm not sure how to do this, either. One of the many good things with rails is that it abstracts the DB...

Comment: No I mean in the terminal, here is a guide on how http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html.  You might not be able to use xcode to encode the files (unless this is no longer true https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3177712?start=0&tstart=0)

Comment: Oh my! So isXCode useless with RoR?

Comment: I would not know enough to say either way, but it might be worth it trying another editor.

Comment: @Btuman I tried running individual migrations, they all fail for the same reason with the same error message. It seems to be a general error dur to encoding...I have no idea how to get out of it...

Comment: So I just need one more thing, and I will have an answer for you. Can you please post the migrations in the question?

Comment: @Btuman 
class CreateClients < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :clients do |t|
      t.string :code
      t.string :nom
      t.string :adresse
      t.string :ville
      t.string :code_postal
      t.string :pays
      t.string :mel
      t.string :password
      t.boolean :actif
      t.float :calculs
      t.date :date_inscription

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

Comment: The problem is that XCode is more than a simple editor, it enables actual coding project management...

Comment: Can you use edit to put the code into the question?

Comment: class CreateClients < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :clients do |t|
      t.string :code
      t.string :nom
      t.string :adresse
      t.string :ville
      t.string :code_postal
      t.string :pays
      t.string :mel
      t.string :password
      t.boolean :actif
      t.float :calculs
      t.date :date_inscription

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

Comment: @Btuman I don't know how to properly edit the code in here...can you please instruct me what to do ?

Comment: I added this code in, to edit, you click the edit button, if you need more help, read the help sections, the faq, and the readme. They are really instructive.

Comment: I still don't know what to do with my problem...

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be the file encoding. It seems that this can be changed in xcode
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/8660411/1026901

Answer (score 0):

did you copy and paste anything into either a migration file or a rake file?

i had the same error as i was pasting in database population data into a rake file.  one little space after a phone number i copied from a docx file did it caused the error for me.